# MediatR generic notification handler not called

Tags: asp.net-core, mediator, mediatr

I'm starting to use MediatR's notification.

In one handler, I want to "log" every notification that comes through. According [to what I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70852634/mediatr-doesnt-handle-contravariant-notifications), I tried the following:

The NotificationHandler:

```
public class NotificationLogger<T> : INotificationHandler<T>
    where T : INotification
{
    private readonly ILogger<NotificationLogger<T>> _logger;
    public NotificationLogger(ILogger<NotificationLogger<T>> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public Task Handle(T notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogTrace($"[{notification.GetType().Name}]: {notification} ");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

One of my notification:

```
public class ServerStartedNotification : ISystemNotification
{
}
public class ISystemNotification : INotification
{
}
```

I register the notification handler:

```
 app.Services.AddTransient(typeof(NotificationLogger<>));
```

In my `Program.cs`, I publish the notification just before waiting on the application:

```
    using (IServiceScope? scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>().Publish(new ServerStartedNotification());
    }

    app.Run();
```

All my breakpoints gets hit, except the `NotificationLogger.Handle`.

Any idea why and what I could check?

Comment: I think what you're trying to archive should be with pipeline behaviours

Comment: @niQu My understanding is that pipeline is for request, not for notifications. I understand that the pipeline might be interesting to do logging. but in my case, it's about to log asynchronous event that will be sent to client through websocket

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally got why it wasn't working. Apparently, registering the notification handler like this isn't enough:

```
app.Services.AddTransient(typeof(NotificationLogger<>));
```

**You must register it like this:**

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(INotificationHandler<>),typeof(NotificationLogger<>));
```

Comment: Is there a way to generically do this? We have hundreds of MediatR slices in our application.